# Cкрипт отображения каталогов, подкаталогов, файлов на PHP

Tags: php

Cкрипт отображения каталогов, подкаталогов, файлов на PHP
ну типо деревы. каталог, файл, подкаталоги если есть, 
заранее спасибо

Comment: а мне соц.сеть в коробке. (со стоимостью менее 100М$ не предлагать). Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск в Google по словам: PHP Directory Listing Script. Имеем:

- [PHP Directory Listing Script](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script)
- [PHP: Directory Listing](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dirlist/)
- [PHP Directory Listing](http://schattenschreiber.org/php-directory-listing/)
- ...

Дальше модифицируем под себя.